# How would you modify elements of an array as a vector?

Tags: arrays, ruby, vector

I have some cartesian points (i.e. array of two values):

```
p0 = [0, 0]
p1 = [20, 20]
```

I need to do some math over it such as `(t+2)*p0` or `(m/v+2)/p1`. I need to modify each element of the array. How would you do this efficiently? My code is something like this:

```
pT = [(t + 2) * p0[0], (t + 2) * p0[1]]
```

but it looks terrible to read. Is there a better way that is more in line with the math form?

Comment: What is `t`, `m` and `v`? What's your expected result? Your example code doesn't actually modify the array, it returns a new array.

Comment: In `(m/v+2)/p1` you are dividing something by an array. Hmmm.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: no, I mean divide the value for each value inside the array. As the multiplication...

Comment: Then you should write it `(1/(m/v+2))*p1`, noting that `m` and `v` are given numbers and `p1` is the array of that name treated as a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `.map`?

```
pT = [p0, p1].map { |p| (t + 2) * p }
```

If you needed to apply a bunch of composed functions for each value, you could do something like:

```
funcs = [
  proc { |p| (t + 2) * p }, # f
  proc { |p| (m / v + 2) / p } # g
]

# applies g(f(p)) for each p
pT = [p0, p1].map { |p| funcs.inject(p) { |p, f| p = f[p] } }
```

Taking this a step further, if you needed a different function for each value:

```
funcs = [
  proc { |p| (t + 2) * p },
  proc { |p| (m / v + 2) / p },
  proc { |p| p }
]

pT = [p0, p1].zip(funcs).map { |p, f| f[p] }
```

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
t = 1 # Or whatever value
pT = p0.map do |p|
  (t+2) * p
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `"matrix"` from the standard library.

```
require "matrix"
p1 = Matrix.row_vector([20, 20]) # => Matrix[[20, 20]]
3 * p1 # => Matrix[[60, 60]]
```

Comment: I continue to be surprised at how little [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) is used. I expect you thought of it as soon as you read "vector" in the title.

Comment: There wasn't vector in the title originally. I added it by edit. The original question was grammatically terrible.

Comment: ...and [Vector](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html).

Comment: Right. I realized that later. They use the same library.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
pT = (t + 2) * p0.first, (t + 2) * p0.last
```

You don't need square brackets around the right-hand-side expression, `pT` will be an array of two elements.

---

If you want it to resemble more like a cartesian point, then, you can alias `Array#first` and `Array#last` to `Array#x` and `Array#y` respectively as shown below

```
class Array
    alias :x :first
    alias :y :last
end
```

---

Then, you can use:

```
pT = (t + 2) * p0.x, (t + 2) * p0.y
```